# Use Stencils in Zurb Foundation 5

Tags: zurb-foundation, stencils

I have used Foundation 4 with Custom Forms before and they work great. With Foundation 5 however I am unable to understand how to use them. Need help!

Going to the URL: http://foundation.zurb.com/stencils.html it gives strange guide on using it which I am not able to understand.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see at

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/upgrading.html#upgrading-the-sass

```
@import "foundation/components/sections";
@import "foundation/components/custom-forms";
```

have both been removed from the foundation framework. If you are looking to continue using custom forms as defined in Foundation 4 and as described in their official documentation

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/components/custom-forms.html

Then you should probably switch back to Foundation 4.

As an alternative, you could always use CSS3 and pseudo elements to style the checkboxes and or radio buttons without having to use a javascript plugin to do it.

Comment: [hongkiat](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/) has a quick tutorial on how to style the checkboxes and radio buttons using CSS3 as I described above.

Or you could use the [prettyCheckable](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/) jQuery plugin.

Comment: Is there a way to use Foundation 4 Custom Forms only?

Comment: I am waiting for your reply

Comment: Accepted your reply as partial

Comment: You could download the foundation 4 forms css and include it below the foundation 5 css in your head section, or just go to the [foundation 5 download](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html) page and uncheck the box for forms, then go to the [foundation 4 download page](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download-f4.html) and then just pull the form classes out of it. This would keep your CSS a little more lightweight.

Comment: Nice but I am sure I will face some minor annoying problems also.

Answer (score 2):

Stensils is a set of tools that helps you to quickly create interfaces in OmniGraffle.
More inforamation about OmniGraffle, here:
http://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle

If you need to create some custom forms for web, better to look here:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html

Comment: No what I was looking for was a tutorial of a guide to change the Forms UI according to the stencils. Foundation 4 simply required using CSS classes and the radio, checkbox and dropdown would change.